# Apply ClipPath to Block Element

Tags: css, svg, clipping

So I'm trying to apply an SVG path as a clipPath to a div, but I can't seem to figure out why it wont do anything in chrome, and display a blank page in Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/no5zmzLc/

```
<p class="target" style="background:lime;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
</p>

<img class="target" src="http://sarasoueidan.com/demos/css-svg-clipping/html-img-clipped-with-css-svg-clippath/flowers.jpg" alt="Cherry Blossoms.">

<svg:svg height="0">
    <svg:clipPath id="c1" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <svg:circle cx="0.25" cy="0.25" r="0.25" id="circle"/>
        <svg:rect x="0.5" y="0.2" width="0.5" height="0.8"/>
    </svg:clipPath>
</svg:svg>

p { width:500px; border:1px solid black; display:inline-block; margin:1em; padding:2em; }
.target { clip-path: url(#c1);   -webkit-clip-path: url(#c1);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS `clip-path`](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) will only work for `-webkit-` browsers.

You could use the `foreignObject` element to import the HTML elements to `svg` element and apply inline `clip-path` to make it work on Firefox as well.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/no5zmzLc/2/)**

```css
p {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 2em;
}
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#cont {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <clipPath id="c1" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle cx="25%" cy="25%" r="25%" id="circle" />
      <rect x="50%" y="20%" width="50%" height="80%" />
    </clipPath>
    <foreignObject clip-path="url(#c1)" width="100%" height="100%">
      <p style="background:lime;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
      <img src="http://sarasoueidan.com/demos/css-svg-clipping/html-img-clipped-with-css-svg-clippath/flowers.jpg" alt="Cherry Blossoms." />
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @Picard102 - I opened your `svg` in Inkscape to find the correct `viewBox` dimensions and I found that it wasn't showing half of your `svg` because the document size was set to default. I've changed the dimensions and I would suggest you use the  `svg` as a background rather than applying the `clip-path`. Here is an example showing how that could be done ---> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/no5zmzLc/6/).